# Is the proof correct and rigorous enough? B. Demidovich, Problems in Mathematical Analysis, §1, ex. 10

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

I'm new to poof based math and I just wanted to make sure that the style I use is rigorous enough or whether it has to be more so. E.g. when rewriting inequalities below I don't mention that denominators are non-zero and therefore such manipulation is allowed. Is that considered rigorous enough? Furthermore, do we really have to show the base case calculation when using mathematical induction or it is sufficient to perform the calculation yourself and mention that the proof is obvious?

---

Prove the following (*B. Demidovich*, *Problems in Mathematical Analysis*, §1, ex. 10):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac{1}{\sqrt {2n + 1}}, n\in N\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 (1)$$

Proof will be done using mathematical induction for $$n \ge 1$$ The case of n = 1 is trivial and holds if we replace n with 1 in (1), since $$ \frac {1}{2} = 0.5 < \frac {1}{\sqrt{3}} \approx 0.57 \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Now, let's prove that if (1) holds for an arbitrary n then it will hold for n+1. Assuming that (1) holds for some n we then have to prove:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac{1}{\sqrt {2n + 3}}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 (3)$$

Using right side of (1), we can conclude that it is sufficient to prove:

$$ \frac{2n+1}{2n + 2} \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt {2n + 1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt {2n + 3}} $$

The inequality can be rewritten as:

$$ \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2n + 2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt {2n + 3}} $$

Or further like this:

$$ \frac{1}{2n + 2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt {2n + 3}\cdot\sqrt {2n + 1} } $$

It is left to show that:

$$ {2n + 2} > \sqrt {2n + 3}\cdot\sqrt {2n + 1} \ \ \ \ \ \ (a) $$

By squaring both sides we can clearly see that the inequality holds for any n.

$$4n^2 + 8n + 4 > 4n^2 +8n + 3\ \ \ \ \ \ (b) $$

Using (2) and (3) we prove that (1) holds for any $n \in N$.

Comment: The proof is fine but to say that $\frac 1 2 <\frac 1 {\sqrt3}$ you should say $3<4$ so $\sqrt 3 <2$ and $\frac 1 2 <\frac 1 {\sqrt3}$. Using approximation to two decimal places makes it less rigorous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If "approximation" means "rounding" then this is no less rigorous. Number rounded to $0.57$ has to be greater then $0.5$, there is no other choice. But proving the rounding, i.e. $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-0.57|<0.01$ may be too hard.

Comment: @freakish $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3} \approx 0.57$ requires a proof.

Comment: Ok, I see the mistake now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just wondered about the last step. Is squaring both sides of the inequality a valid trick here? If so, then why?

Comment: @Eval Yes, you can square, because both sides are positive.

Comment: @egreg How do we know that $\sqrt {2n + 3}\cdot\sqrt {2n + 1}$ is positive if each sqrt has two solutions, namely +- solutions.

Comment: @Eval If $x>0$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is the *positive* square root. Look at what you need to prove to begin with!

Comment: @egreg Say x = 4. Then there are two numbers that could've produced 4 when multiplied with themselves. It is -2 and 2. Why is one solution valid and another one is not (namely the negative one), how do we know that in this particular case the positive one holds and not the negative one?

Comment: I see, I guess by the *definition* of sqrt for positive numbers itself, it is meant that the function produces positive numbers as a result, out of these two possibilities.

Comment: @Eval I repeat: the standard convention is that $y=\sqrt{x}$ ***if and only if*** $y\ge0$ and $y^2=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct.

For $n=1$, the left-hand side is $1/2$ and the right-hand side is $1/\sqrt{3}$. Since $1/4<1/3$, you also have $1/2<1/\sqrt{3}$.

Suppose the inequality holds for $n$; then, by the induction hypothesis,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{(2k-1)}{2k}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}
$$
and we just need to check that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+3}}
$$
that is,
$$
\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\le2n+2=\frac{(2n+1)+(2n+3)}{2}
$$
which is a case of AM-GM.